# change from template to ng-template

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I'm getting this error with angular 4:

```
The <template> element is deprecated. Use <ng-template> instead ("
    [attr.tabIndex]="-1"
    [ngClass]="{'k-item': true}">
    [WARNING ->]<template *ngIf="template"
        [templateContext]="{
```

are you planning on updating this for the final release?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the components have been updated and released with Angular 4 support.